# How to migrate Postgres array data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I need to change an array of ids in postgres from being integers to being uuids.  It's in a Rails app, and there are other parts to this, but I can't figure this out.

I could do it in ActiveRecord, but I can't figure out how to get the sql to do this.

```
add_column :templates, :uuids, :uuid, array: true
Template.find_each do |template|
  new_ids = template.conversations.map do |conversation_id|
    conversation = Conversation.find_by(id: conversation_id)
    conversation.uuid
  end
  template.update_column(:uuids, new_ids)
end
remove_column :templates, :conversations
rename_column :templates, :uuids, :conversations
```

I would expect this to work, but it tells me that no column `uuids` exists on templates.

Comment: what is the column name? is it uuid or uuids?

Comment: Have you tried adding `Template.reset_column_information` after the column creation and before the data migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running:

```
Template.reset_column_information
```

After the column is created and before the data migration should refresh the cache and discover the new column.
This is the same for any single migration file which does both column manipulation and data migrations.

The alternative is to split this over 2-3 migrations. Like so:

1. Create column
2. Data migration
3. Column remove & rename

This second approach has the added benefit that if your data migration fails for any reason you’re not left in a pseudo-state where the first column has been created already. This state means that trying to rerun the migration will fail as the column already exists.